# i have a dataframe in r how to convert into character with pipe (|) symbol to pass into grep command

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, dplyr

```
a1<-"NDA|BJP|advani|modi|narendra|namo"


View(src_in)
a coward is incapable of exhibiting love it is the prerogative of the brave mahatma gandhi tropa de paz somostropadepaz
a goal properly set is halfway reached zig ziglar quotes f f ghargharmodi
a modi victory makes it easier for companies and lenders to raise equity on the stock market myvoteformodi  


ret_id <- grep(a1,src_in[,4],ignore.case=TRUE) 
src_out <- src_in[ret_id,] 


View(src_out)  
a goal properly set is halfway reached zig ziglar quotes f f ghargharmodi
a modi victory makes it easier for companies and lenders to raise equity on the stock market myvoteformodi
```

ret_id holds the index of dataframe(src_in) where grep command is true.Means value of a1 present in src_in 4th field  (this is text filed which contains tweet).

but now due to so many search words presents in our database therefore we are stored in csv file format.

file reading command

```
df<-read.csv("word.csv")
```

file stored in a dataframe .....named df

View(df)

```
1   UPA  
2   NCP  
3   Gandhi  
4   Rahul  
5   pappu  
6   Sonia
```

My question is how to convert df into a1 format which looks same and add | between two word for pass into grep command.

```
UPA|NCP|Gandhi|Rahul|pappu|Sonia
```

so we can pass into grep command as argument like **a1**

Comment: with `paste0(df[,1],collapse="|")` ?

Comment: how to concatenate a1 a2 a3 with pipe @CathG beacuse multiple csv are there????

Comment: `paste0(c(a1,a2,a3),collapse="|")`